# Unable to install Lombok 1.18.10

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, lombok

I am running a spring boot application using jdk version 19 but am unable to install lombok. I am using maven 3.8.1

```
    class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module @0x58909d73) cannot access class   com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0x58909d73
```

I have tried changing the jdk to lower versions

Comment: How do you install maven? Shouldn't it be a pom entry?

Comment: Java 19 is not supported yet. https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3264

Comment: @f1sh it comes with intellj

Comment: @PartickDawson the IDE plugin comes with intellij. You still need it in your pom if you are using maven to build your project.

Answer (score -1):

Try latest lombok version `v1.18.24` with JDK18. Their compatibility is listed in [changelog](https://projectlombok.org/changelog)

Comment: tried that, it breaks other dependencies

Comment: JDK18 is obsolete and should not be used.